# Issue in Downloading the Image and Updating the listView

Tags: android, listview, runnable, executorservice

I am getting the issues in downloading the image and Updating the ImageView,I am downloading the image using ExecutorServices,but the  problem i am facing is,as of scenario,I am using base adapter to display the Imageview in the list.Image gets downloaded but the both of the images gets updated in firstImage View only.

So Bitmap is getting updated in same imageView,has anyone faced similar sort of issue

For eg,I am downloading 2 images,It is creating 2 instances of ImageDownloader,all runs good till the Run() of that class in the line of before download section,Once Image gets downloaded,I am getting object reference of ImageView of the First Image Downloader class,I am not sure of why?I think it is no where related to listview,or adapter,It is more related to Executor and Runnable Implementation,

public class ImageLoader {

```
ExecutorService mExecutorService = null;
static ImageLoader mLoader = null;
Handler mImageHandler = null ;
DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = null;
int mRequiredWidth =0 , mRequiredHeight = 0;
Map<String,ImageView> mToLoadObjects = Collections.synchronizedMap(
        new WeakHashMap<String, ImageView>());
ArrayList<String> toloadURL = new ArrayList<String>();
protected Resources mResources = null;
MyImageCache mMemoryCache;
Activity activity;
public static final String LOGGER = "ImageLoader";

public ImageLoader(Activity context){
  mExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
  mImageHandler = new Handler();
  mResources = context.getResources();
  activity = context;
  mMemoryCache  = new MyImageCache();
  mDisplayMetrics  = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  mRequiredWidth = mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
  mRequiredHeight = mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;

}



public void loadImage (String url,ImageView imageView){     
    try {
        if (imageView != null) {
           if (!toloadURL.contains(url)) {
                toloadURL.add(url);
                mExecutorService.execute(new ImageDownloader(url,imageView));
            } 
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.v("Exception Occurs>>",""+e.getMessage());
    }
}




class ImageDownloader implements  Runnable{
    String imageUrl;
    ImageView downloadableImageView;
    ImageDownloader loader;


    ImageDownloader(String url,ImageView view){
        Log.v(LOGGER,"Within ImageDownloader "+url +"this>>>"+this);
        loader = this;
        imageUrl = url;
        downloadableImageView  = view;
        Log.v(LOGGER,"Within ImageDownloader "+downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>"+this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v(LOGGER, "run" + downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>>>"+this);
        Bitmap tempBitmap = null;
        tempBitmap = (mMemoryCache.getBitmapFromMemCache(imageUrl));
        try{
            if(tempBitmap!=null){
                Log.v(LOGGER,"ImageBitmap Wid>>>>>>"+downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>>"+this+""+tempBitmap.getWidth());
                Log.v(LOGGER,"ImageBitmap Ht>>>>>>"+downloadableImageView.getTag()+ "this>>>>"+this+""+tempBitmap.getHeight());
                downloadableImageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
            }else{
                Log.v(LOGGER, "else to download Tag is" + downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>>>"+this);//Works till this point

                final Bitmap tempBitmap1 = getBitmap(imageUrl);
                Log.v(LOGGER, "else to download Tag is " + downloadableImageView.getTag() + "After Download>>>" + tempBitmap1.getWidth() + "this>>>>>" + this);//Issue happens here
                mMemoryCache.addBitmapToMemoryCache(imageUrl, tempBitmap1);
                Log.v("LOGGER, else to download Tag is "+downloadableImageView.getTag()+"After Cache>>>", "" + downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>>"+this);
                if(tempBitmap1!=null){
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.v("LOGGER, else to download Tag is "+downloadableImageView.getTag()+"RunOnUIThread>>>", "" + downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>>"+loader);
                            downloadableImageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap1);
                            downloadableImageView.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v("ExceptionBitmap",""+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String imageUrl){
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        try {
            Log.v("Within getBitmap ","run");
            URL uri = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)uri.openConnection();
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
             bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream(connection.getInputStream(), mRequiredWidth, mRequiredHeight);

        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.v("ExceptionLoad",""+e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}

public  Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromInputStream(InputStream in
                                                        , int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    InputStream copyiInputStream1 = null;
    InputStream copyiInputStream2 = null;
    try {
        byte[] data = InputStreamTOByte(in);
        copyiInputStream1 = byteTOInputStream(data);
        copyiInputStream2 = byteTOInputStream(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(copyiInputStream1, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(copyiInputStream2, null, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public InputStream byteTOInputStream(byte[] in) throws Exception{

    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(in);
    return is;
}

public byte[] InputStreamTOByte(InputStream in) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[1024*16];
    int count = -1;
    while((count = in.read(data,0,1024*16)) != -1)
        outStream.write(data, 0, count);

    data = null;
    return outStream.toByteArray();
}


class BitmapUpdater implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;

    public BitmapUpdater(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView){
        bitmap=bitmap;
        imageView =imageView;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        // Show bitmap on UI
        if(bitmap!=null){
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
        }
        else
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.account_photo_book_detail2);
    }
}
```

}

I have attached Logs for reference,Please help in sorting out this issue

```
Image Tag(0,1)--> I applied Tag for ImageView to sort out the Image View instance
```

### Thread 1:(ImageDownloader1 Thread Object)

04-06 17:05:57.662  20053-20053/com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp V/ImageLoader﹕ Within ImageDownloader https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s1024/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpgthis>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@435058b0
04-06 17:05:57.662  20053-20053/com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp V/ImageLoader﹕ Within ImageDownloader 0(imageViewObjectTag)this>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@

04-06 17:05:57.664  20053-20130/com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp V/ImageLoader﹕ else to download Tag is0(imageViewObjectTag)this>>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@435058b0

### Thread 2:((ImageDownloader2 Thread Object))

04-06 17:05:57.666  20053-20053/com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp V/ImageLoader﹕ Within ImageDownloader https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s1024/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpgthis>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@431a5d58
04-06 17:05:57.666  20053-20053/com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp V/ImageLoader﹕ Within ImageDownloader 1(imageView)this>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@431a5d58

---

### Thread 1 & 2 run ():

20053-20130/com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp V/ImageLoader﹕ run 0(imageViewObjectTag)this>>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@435058b0
20053-20131/com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp V/ImageLoader﹕ run 1(imageViewObjectTag)this>>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@431a5d58

else to download Tag is1this>>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@431a5d58

### ((ImageDownloader1 Thread Object)) after download:

else to download Tag is 0(imageViewObjectTag)After Download>>>1024this>>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@435058b0//(ImageDownloader1 Object))
else to download Tag is 0(imageViewObjectTag)After Cache>>>﹕ 0this>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@435058b0//(ImageDownloader1 Object))
else to download Tag is 0(imageViewObjectTag)RunOnUIThread>>>﹕ 0this>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@435058b0//(ImageDownloader1 Object))

All Ok this Till this Point

### ((ImageDownloader2 Thread Object))after download:

else to download Tag is 0(imageViewObjectTag)After Download>>>1024this>>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@431a5d58//(ImageDownloader2 Object with ImageView tag coming as 0 different which should be tag1))
else to download Tag is 0(imageViewObjectTag)After Cache>>>﹕ 0this>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@431a5d58 //(ImageDownloader2 Object with ImageView tag coming as 0 different which should be tag1))
else to download Tag is 0(imageViewObjectTag)RunOnUIThread>>>﹕ 0this>>>>com.xxx.xxxxmobileapp.Imagebook.network.ImageLoader$ImageDownloader@431a5d58//(ImageDownloader2 Object with ImageView tag coming as 0 different which should be tag1))

Comment: *I feel issue is Reference passed to network loader class is same* - No, I don't think so, as you passed `holder.testImageView` , must be something else.

Comment: how to send different image view,or what is correct way of doing it

Comment: @Rakesh   my friend, why can't you use universal image loader to download your images? i use it and my listview which uses baseAdapter gets updated very very well like nobody's business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,final i  got the issue solved through my friend [arunkumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2294369/arunkumar)

Kudos to him :)

I tried two things,

1)To find out the problem is with list view or executor service implementation.To find out i replaced the list view with the Linear Layout and added as view which worked successfully which confirms problem is with listview not with executor service implementation.

2)Real issue why image gets updated in first Image is because of view  ID(ImageView.getID()) is same ,

i set the ID instead of setting tag,and i passed the id to image loader class,and i retreived the image through findViewById(SetID),which worked

I am adding some pieces of code which will be helpful

### for setting the ID in adapter class:

```
 final ImageView imageView = holder.jobImageView;
       holder.jobImageView.setId(position);
       loader.loadImage(object.getlargeImageUrl(),holder.jobImageView,position);
```

### For getting the ID in adapter class:

```
final Bitmap tempBitmap1 = getBitmap(imageUrl);
                Log.v(LOGGER, "else to download Tag is " +imageViewId + "After Download>>>" + tempBitmap1.getWidth() + "this>>>>>" + this);
                mMemoryCache.addBitmapToMemoryCache(imageUrl, tempBitmap1);
                downloadableImageView = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(imageViewId);
                Log.v("LOGGER, else to download Tag is "+downloadableImageView.getTag()+"After Cache>>>", "" + downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>>"+this);
                if(tempBitmap1!=null){
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.v("LOGGER, else to download Tag is " + downloadableImageView.getTag() + "RunOnUIThread>>>", "" + downloadableImageView.getTag() + "this>>>>" + loader);

                            downloadableImageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap1);
                            //downloadableImageView.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use Glide library for image downloading?

it does all the things in just one line.

here is the syntax of it

```
Glide.with(context).load(URL).into(Imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a recycling issue, and the problem is that the initial `ImageView`, after the download completes, might represent another position in list. You see the issue is happening after `getBitmap(imageUrl)` call, but theoretically, it might happen earlier, too. I'm not sure whether the `BitmapUpdater` is used in your code, but at the first sight, it's not related to your situation.

So in order to fix this problem, you need to implement a mechanism to avoid `ImageView` being updated with an "old" bitmap. You could use the `tag` property of the `ImageView`, to save the actual URL that needs to be displayed. If the URL in the image's `tag` is different than the one actually used for downloading, just cache the image. You could do something like

```
public void loadImage (String url,ImageView imageView){
    if(imageView != null) imageView.setTag(url);
    [...]
}
```

and

```
if(tempBitmap1!=null){
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v("LOGGER, else to download Tag is " + downloadableImageView.getTag()+"RunOnUIThread>>>", "" + downloadableImageView.getTag()+"this>>>>"+loader);
            if(downloadableImageView.getTag().equals(imageUrl) {
                downloadableImageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap1);
            }
            else Log.v(LOGGER, "the image no longer wants this URL, ignoring");
            //downloadableImageView.requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

Also, I would recommend to avoid `downloadableImageView.requestLayout();` since it will cause the whole layout to be measured, and in your situation, it's not needed.

Comment: Hi Ana,This is also not fruitful,Only first imageView is updated,It is not solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso image loading library.
Link for documentation of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 0):

With a heavy job like decoding large bitmap in local storage or from stream online, we must do it in a worked thread, problem is after finished decoding, the imageview has been recycled. Solve it:

```
// In your adapter (onCreateView)
bitmap = yourBitmapCache.get(position);
if (bitmap != null)
    yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
else if (imageLoaderManager.isLoading.get(position) == false){
    imagerLoaderManager.load(position, url);
}


// Create Callback interface
interface Callback {
     void onFinishLoad(int position, Bitmap bm);
}

// Create inner class ImageLoaderManager
class ImageLoaderManager {
    Hasmap<Integer, Boolean> isLoading = new Hasmap<>();
    Callback callback = new Callback() {
         @Override
         void onFinishLoad(int position, Bitmap bitmap){
             isLoading.put(position, false);
             if (bitmap != null) {
                  yourBitmapCache.put(position, bitmap)
                  activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run(){
                            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                            // If you use recycler view adapter: notifyItemChanged(position)
                       }
                  });

             }
         }
    };

    public void load(int position, String url){
         isLoading.put(position, true);
         newYourImageLoader(url, position, callback).start();
         // when loader finish job, 
         // it's must call back using callback.onFinishLoad(given position, bitmap result);
    }
}
```

No need to hold `ImageView` reference in my solution. Just remember `position` and requires adapter reload the item view at this position after decoding task finished, now bitmap has already exist in `yourBitmapCache`.